# Django rest serializer.data is an empty OrderedDict()

Tags: django, python-2.7, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime


class Staff(models.Model):
    employer = models.ForeignKey("shops.Shop")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Here is my serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from staff.models import Staff 


class StaffSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Staff
        fields = ("id", "employer", "user")
```

Here is my view:

```
from staff.models import Staff
from staff.serializers import StaffSerializer
from rest_framework import  generics
from rest_framework.response import Response



class StaffList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Staff.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StaffSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = StaffSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        print queryset
        print serializer
        print serializer.data
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When viewing this page on the web browsable API this is what I see:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

[
    {}
]
```

and the result of printing serializer.data and queryset is this:

```
{<Staff: Alex>}
StaffSerializer([<Staff: Alex>], many=True):
[OrderedDict()]
```

Is there something wrong with my serializer or is this another issue all together?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to use **serializers.ModelSerializer** not a **serializers.Serializer** if you are working with models and querysets.

If you are using serializers.Serializer you need to define field in it manually. Like this:

```
class StaffSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  id = serializers.IntegerField()
  content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
```

etc.
You cant reference them in meta like with ModelSerializer. Docs on ModelSerializer can be found [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

Comment: This happens to me when I use `serializers.Serializer`. Do you have any clue?

Comment: This is very late, but I was having the same problem when overridding serializers.ModelSerializer.__init__ in my instance. Even if the __init__ did nothing but a super() back up the chain.

Comment: Another reason for getting empty ordered dicts - you might have forgotton to create actual instances of your serializer. If you've just referenced the serializer (`foo = FooSerializer`) instead of creating an instance (`foo = FooSerializer()`), the field won't get resolved properly. The same is the case for the built-in serializers for primitive types. So - make sure you're doing `IntegerField()` and not just `IntegerField`.